# Why chrome crashes?

Tags: javascript

hi :) why chrome tab crashes with math.random? this code is for a casual placement of object in a matrix, but chrome crashed and can't understand the reason... thanks for help and sorry for bad english

```
function posOggetti(oggetto, numOggetti)
        {
            var count = 0;
            while(count < numOggetti)
            {
                if(posOggetto(oggetto))
                    count++;
            }
        }

        function posOggetto(oggetto)
        {
            var x = generaIntero(8-1);
            var y = generaIntero(12-1);
            if(piano[x][y] == 0)
            {
                piano[x][y] = oggetto;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function generaIntero(N)
        {
            var r = Math.random() * N;
            var ri = Math.round(r);
            return ri
        }
```

Comment: sound like this condition is never met, `posOggetto(oggetto)`

Comment: What is `piano`?  If the elements are never zero, then the loop in the first function will run forever (and the browser will complain).

Comment: piano is the matrix where the object are placed

Comment: Well randomly selecting things and hoping at some point you hit something is zero.... well seems like it you never seem to hit zero. Maybe you need to rethink how you grab random locations so it is not infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by infinite loop.

In function `posOgetti`, if `posOgetto` returns `false`, the browser will crash. You can force loop exit in this scenario.

```
function posOggetti(oggetto, numOggetti)
    {
        var count = 0;
        while(count < numOggetti)
        {
            if(posOggetto(oggetto))
                count++;
            else
                count = numOggetti;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's worked :D but i didn't see the objects placed. thank anyway

Comment: Well, off course quitting the loop as soon as it fails to find an element which isn't 0 won't do much...

Answer (score 0):

Your code picks a random element of a 2D array until it finds one which contains the value 0. Then, it sets this element to `oggetto`. This process repeats `numOggetti` times.

But it's possible that the random function will never pick an element which isn't 0, and so it will loop forever. I don't know what you are trying to do, but when working with code that picks things randomly, avoid "trying until it works" scenarios and always think of the worst case.